# How to make execution update reverse query mysql by id?

Tags: mysql

I have 5 rows with ID: 1,2,3,4,5.

Then I made a query to try change those ID to: 2,3,4,5,6

```
Update table set `id` = `id` + 1
```

Then i get:

> Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'.

I understand this query be executed by ID 1 first and the cause is the PRIMARY 2 was existed.

So my question is how to make a query has been executed by ID from 5 to 1.

Comment: you should try `ORDER BY id DESC` and see if it works

Comment: @Tin Tran, it will work.

Comment: Many thanks. It so simple but i cannot thought of

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Created a table num_sample with numbers from 1 to 100. Defined a primary key on the column num. And wrote this update

```
update num_sample set num = num + 1 order by num desc limit 100;
```

Worked absolutely fine in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` :

```
SET @MAX_ID = SELECT MAX(ID) FROM YOUR_TABLE;

UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET ID = ID + @MAX_ID

UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET ID = ID - @MAX_ID - 1
```